# Setting TeamCity job build number using Maven exec:exec

Tags: windows, maven, teamcity

In a TeamCity job I'm trying to read Maven project version from the root `pom.xml` e.g. `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and change the build number to `1.0.0-N` where `N` is a value of `%build.counter%`. The goal is to replace `SNAPSHOT` with a build identifier.

So far I tried to combine [`build-helper:parse-version`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) together with [`exec:exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to call `echo` to write `##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.0-1']` in the build log and change the build number.

On my workstation I can execute following Maven command to print the `##teamcity` instruction in the command line:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version exec:exec \ 
  -Dexec.executable="echo" \
  -Dexec.args="##teamcity[buildNumber '${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}-%build.counter%']"
```

However when I define a Maven Step in my TeamCity build then TeamCity parses the `##teamcity` instruction directly from the Maven command line invocation printed in the build logs resulting in following Maven call:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version exec:exec \ 
  -Dexec.executable="echo" \
  -Dexec.args=""
```

and following being done by TeamCity:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber '${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}-11']
```

Is there a way to escape the parameter containing `##teamcity` in the Maven command line invocation so TeamCity ignores it during Maven invocation but passes it to `exec:exec` Maven goal so it can output:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.0-11']
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way to achieve my goal using TeamCity Build Steps and without modifying project's `pom.xml`. Do I have to use PowerShell or Batch script for this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case. I tried experimenting with this and got the positive result.
The echo command was omitting the single quote in the final output so I never managed to get TeamCity to consume the service message.

Instead of calling the Maven build step, I defined Command Line build step that launched a script. The scripts task is to generate the desired output:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.0-61']
```

The script itself is really ugly, but kinda works. Perhaps you can come up with more elegant solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ARGUMENTS="teamcity[buildNumber 'Q\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.
mvn build-helper:parse-version exec:exec -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args="$ARGUMENTS" |  grep teamcity | sed "s/Q/\'/g" | awk '{print "##"$0}'
```

For some reason, if I put ## into the initial string and didn't use awk at the end of the command sequence, then it didn't work and I ended up with a result like '1.0.0-???', hence the hack with awk at the end.

Hope this helps.

[image: Results in TeamCity]

Comment: Ended up with a PowerShell script myself which apparently doesn't output `###teamcity` in the TeamCity build log when invoked. I still have no idea how to escape TeamCity service message in the step invocation arguments :(